# I need to send an object from an html form as a json string, but I have a string

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, rest, spring-mvc

I  try to send an ajax request to my rest controller to edit an object user. One of the fields of it is a list of roles. Each role has Id and name, but when I fill the form I put this option in a select field as a text of its name. Here is the fragment:

```
 $.ajax({
                        url: '/api/roles/',
                        method: 'get',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        success: function (result) {
                            $('#roles').empty();
                            $.each(result, function (k, v) {
                                var option = new Option(v.name, v.name);
                                $("#roles").append(option);
                            });

                        }
                    })
```

When I send the form values the list of roles goes as a list of strings, so the rest controller makes an object without the id field. What is the best way to fix it? I send it like this:

```
 $.ajax({
            url: '/api/users',
            async: true,
            // dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json",
            type: "PUT",
             data:
             JSON.stringify(   {
                id : jQuery('#id').val(),
                username: jQuery('#username').val(),
                password: jQuery('#password').val(),
                roles : jQuery('#roles').val()

            })

        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ajax call to fill the select list

```
var option = new Option(v.name, v.name);
$("#roles").append(option);
```

creates an option element in HTML like

```
<option value="name">name</option>
```

The data you send with your second ajax call includes the value attribute of the selected option element. If you need the id of the role for your "/api/users" controller, you simply need to set the id in the first place.

So just initiate the option elements in a way like

```
var option = new Option(v.name, v.id);
$("#roles").append(option);
```

and you will get

```
<option value="id">name</option>
```

This way you will get the id of the selected role for the /api/users script when calling jQuery('#roles').val().

Comment: In this case, the field name in the resulting object gets the id value. For some reason, only the name field can be set here.

Comment: That's a bit weird. But this can only be a result of the new Option call. So I would suggest to use another way to add the elements to the select list and not to use the Option object. Something like `$('#roles').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", role.id).text(role.name));` should do the trick.